# Angularjs/TypeScript - To send a param in component

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am working with an application that combines angularjs and typescript.

I have created a component to control errors, but I do not know how to read in my controller the param sent in my component for to show it in screen.

This is my error component (errors.component.ts):

```
module MainErrors.Components {
    'use strict';

    export class MainErrorsComp extends MiApp.Components.ParentComponent {

        public templateUrl: string | Function;
        public controller: string | Function | (string | Function)[];

        static instance(): ng.IComponentOptions {
            return new MainErrorsComp();
        }

        constructor() {
            super();

            let bindings =  {
              msgErrorMicro: '='
            }
            this.templateUrl = '/templates/errors.html';
            this.controller = 'mainErrorsController as MainErrCtrl';
            this.setBindings(bindings);
        }

    }
}
```

This is my error controller (errors.controller.ts):

```
 constructor(public $injector, public $scope) {
      super($injector);

      let vm = this;

      vm.setInjections($injector);
      vm.initComp();

      vm.msgError = // Here I want to collect the value of the msgErrorMicro parameter that I send from a html in the component, but I do not know how to do it

    }
```

This is the html (errors.html)

```
<p>{{MainErrCtrl.msgError}}</p>
```

Now I call my error component from any html, for example, from login.html:

```
<main-errors-comp msg-error-micro="Problems to connect from login"></main-errors-comp>
```

I want the value of the "msg-error-micro" parameter to be loaded in the varible vm.msgError of "errors.controller.ts"

How I could do it?

Comment: Use `'@'` attribute binding instead of `'='` two way binding. Also if you want the scope variable to be `msgErr`, use `let bindings = {'msgErr': '@msgErrMicro'};` For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) and [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'@'` attribute binding instead of `'='` two way binding. Also if you want the scope variable to be `msgErr`, use:

```
let bindings = {'msgErr': '@msgErrMicro'};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).